# Lightweight Hadoop Distribution

Tags: hadoop, hive, udf

I want to learn to develop UDFs for Hive. I downloaded Cloudera's quickstart virtual machine for virtualbox, but it takes 8GB of memory to run Cloudera Manager. I have a dev machine with only 8GB so running Cloudera's Hadoop distribution is not possible.

Is there a lightweight Hadoop distribution I can use to learn the Hadoop/Hive world?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera Manager is turned off by default in that VM, and is not needed for your use case. You should be able to run CDH alone with 8GB RAM available.